# First loading of a page

Tags: rest, single-page-application

I have a single page app working over REST services.

My services have the standard HTTP methods.

When first loading a page, it has many elements, such as menus, dropdowns, information about general context (user messages,user alerts, etc).

Am I supposed to have a REST service to load each page element or should I load all the page data at once?

If loading all data at once, a GET non parametrized is to load a list Stocks what should I do to load the all the page context (with context I mean the page objects)

I mean, will I have lots of services just to load a menu, dropdown list, the number of unread messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a get service which can serve you with all the data you need at page load, this will be acting as a template service to create your stage.

Comment: That's a good idea.
I thought something like that, but making a non web api controller (with actions) to return  the background of any page and get the specific data (stock for example) of each page from its service as said by @Fermin. But the idea of both of you sounds more professional.

Answer (score 0):

you could have only two ajax calls (two rest services). The first one to load context data and the second one to load stock data.

I recommend you to use promises, so in that way you could give the control to the user once all data is loaded correctly.

See this article: https://github.com/kriskowal/q

I hope it helps.